# Where is "mysqld-auto.cnf" located? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database, windows, file-location

I use **MySQL** on **Windows**. At the moment, I'm looking for **"mysqld-auto.cnf"** to check **persisted system variables** but I couldn't find it.

Actually, I could find **"my.ini"** whose path is as shown below and I know that for Windows, **"my.ini"** is used instead of **"my.cnf"**.

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini
```

My questions:

1. For **Windows**, is **other equivalent file** used instead of **"mysqld-auto.cnf"** like **"my.cnf"** and **"my.ini"**?
2. Where is **"mysqld-auto.cnf"** located on **Windows**?

Answer (score 0):

On **Windows**, **"mysqld-auto.cnf"** is located at **the path below** and as you already noticed, **the same file name "mysqld-auto.cnf"** is also used for **Windows** different from **"my.cnf"** and **"my.ini"**:

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\mysqld-auto.cnf
```